# Jest/Enzyme Test Coverage For Simple Function

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

This is probably a super simple question, but I'm stumped trying to figure out why I'm not getting 100% coverage in my Jest/Enzyme test.

I have a function that simply declares a variable.  Actually, it makes a call to an API to assign the variable, but that API call is already tested elsewhere, and I still get incomplete coverage even by just saying:

```
testFunction() {
   const foo = "foo";
}
```

My test coverage report says that the one line of code within that function isn't covered.  I know its probably not a big deal, but it's driving me crazy...

Comment: What line is not covered? Provide the whole table with coverage report please

Comment: It's only the line that says 'const foo = "foo";'

Comment: Need more information